# how to add border on bottom only in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add border on **bottom** of the layout. I know i can use `Divider` composable but i just want to learn *how to draw a border*.

Currently, I can add border for all sides which is not what I want.

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, Color.LightGray))
) {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Switch(checked = true, onCheckedChange = {})
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, "Remove", tint = Color.Gray)
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no functionality to achieve it. Have you considered adding another child element for the row scope which acts as a border?

Comment: It is surprising that there is no straightforward solution for this! Using a divider seems like the best solution for me!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the **`drawBehind`** modifier to draw a line.
Something like:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .drawBehind {

            val strokeWidth = indicatorWidth.value * density
            val y = size.height - strokeWidth / 2

            drawLine(
                Color.LightGray,
                Offset(0f, y),
                Offset(size.width, y),
                strokeWidth
            )
        }){
    //....
}
```

[image]

If you prefer you can build your custom Modifier with the same code above

```
fun Modifier.bottomBorder(strokeWidth: Dp, color: Color) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current    
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }

        Modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height - strokeWidthPx/2

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                end = Offset(x = width , y = height),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )
        }
    }
)
```

and then just apply it:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .bottomBorder(1.dp, DarkGray)
){
    //Row content
}
```

Comment: I don't like this solution but it's fairly simple and it works. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Using a "Divider" worked for me,

```
Column {
        Divider (
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(1.dp)  
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
// Something else
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Although not an answer to the asked question, this is still a neat solution that also happens to be semantically correct in many use cases for a single side border

Answer (score 4):

Edited taking into account Arthur Khazbs comments:

You can define a rectangular Shape on the bottom of your element, using the bottom line thickness in Dp as parameter:

```
@Composable
private fun getBottomLineShape(lineThicknessDp: Dp) : Shape {
    val lineThicknessPx = with(LocalDensity.current) {lineThicknessDp.toPx()}
    return GenericShape { size, _ ->
        // 1) Bottom-left corner
        moveTo(0f, size.height)
        // 2) Bottom-right corner
        lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        // 3) Top-right corner
        lineTo(size.width, size.height - lineThicknessPx)
        // 4) Top-left corner
        lineTo(0f, size.height - lineThicknessPx)
    }
}
```

And then use it in the border modifier like this:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
       .height(rowHeight)
       .border(width = lineThicknessDp,
               color = Color.Black,
               shape = getBottomLineShape(lineThicknessDp))
) {
  // Stuff in the row
}
```

Comment: This approach is great! It is (a) exactly what was asked for and (b) exactly what `.border` and `Shape` are intended for. However, ideally, I think `bottomLineThickness` should be in `Dp` and should be converted to `Float` px under the hood of the `Shape` creation. From what I can see, `GenericShape` does not respect the `Density` passed to its `createOutline`, so I think creating a custom subtype of `Shape` is worth a shot here.

Comment: Or as a simple, but a bit hacky solution, one could annotate getBottomLineShape as @Composable and convert `Dp` using `LocalDensity.current` inside it.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw a line in a draw scope. In my opinion, a divider looks cleaner in code.

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier
  .drawWithContent {
    drawContent()
    clipRect { // Not needed if you do not care about painting half stroke outside
      val strokeWidth = Stroke.DefaultMiter
      val y = size.height // - strokeWidth 
          // if the whole line should be inside component
      drawLine(
        brush = SolidColor(Color.Red),
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = StrokeCap.Square,
        start = Offset.Zero.copy(y = y),
        end = Offset(x = size.width, y = y)
      )
    }
  }
) {
  Text("test")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah this oughta do it:-

```
@Suppress("UnnecessaryComposedModifier")
fun Modifier.topRectBorder(width: Dp = Dp.Hairline, brush: Brush = SolidColor(Color.Black)): Modifier = composed(
    factory = {
        this.then(
            Modifier.drawWithCache {
                onDrawWithContent {
                    drawContent()
                    drawLine(brush, Offset(width.value, 0f), Offset(size.width - width.value, 0f))
                }
            }
        )
    },
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "border"
        properties["width"] = width
        if (brush is SolidColor) {
            properties["color"] = brush.value
            value = brush.value
        } else {
            properties["brush"] = brush
        }
        properties["shape"] = RectangleShape
    }
)
```

Comment: This is the way the original border Modifier is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it easily with chaining modifiers. this even lets you do different size lines on each side if you want, and different shape borders

what you're looking for

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline)
                       .padding(bottom = 1.dp)
                       .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
) {...}
```

more complex

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                       .padding(horizontal = 1.dp, vertical = 2.dp)
                       .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable private fun BottomBorder () {
    Text(
        text = "Hello, world!",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp) // some space around the Text component
            .drawWithContent {
                drawContent()
                drawLine(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    start = Offset(0f, size.height),
                    end = Offset(size.width, size.height),
                    strokeWidth = 2f
                )
            }
    )
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this Divider on bottom of your Composable view :

```
Divider(
        color = Color.LightGray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(0.5.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )
```

Comment: Sounds like a right way  of implementing, thanks!